# Feature spec making sure not signed in User can't see a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following feature rspec:

```
feature 'User creates a club' do
  scenario 'with a valid name' do
      sign_in
      visit new_club_path  
      fill_in 'Name', :with => 'Unio Esportiva'
  end

  scenario 'user is not signed in' do
    visit new_club_path  
    # What should I test here?
  end
end
```

The second scenario is the one that brings me doubts. What should I test if I want to make sure that a non signed in User, can't access that page? Should I test that he is redirected to the sign_in page? Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You need to test for what WILL happen when the user tries to access the page.  What you choose to test out of that is a matter of taste and style:

- test current_user is nil
- test user is redirected to wherever the redirect is
- test for page content

Now, per this response, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173946/rspec-what-is-the-difference-between-a-feature-and-a-request-spec , you should assert against the page in a feature spec.  So what SHOULD you see.  But you may want to test the redirect using a request spec, and probably test the current_user assignment when testing the controller. Make sense?